# Bash alias not working for Python script

Tags: python, bash, pygame, alias

Trying to set a Bash alias in order to run a Python script for Pygame.
I have the `android.py` acript in, `/usr/local/bin/pgs4a-0.9.6/andoid.py`.

Bash alias: `alias pyg='python /usr/local/bin/pgs4a-0.9.6/android.py'`

When I run `python android.py` when I am in the folder in executes just fine, but when I do it from any other folder or using the alias, I get the following error.

```
pyg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pgs4a-0.9.6/android.py", line 11, in <module>
    import interface
ImportError: No module named interface
```

Can anybody explain to me why this is?

Comment: Try doing this with a function instead, they're _much_ more flexible; aliases are really only suitable for simple stuff. To quote the bash man: "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alias pyg='PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/bin/pgs4a-0.9.6 python /usr/local/bin/pgs4a-0.9.6/android.py'
```

That is, set your $PYTHONPATH environment variable to contain the directory with the code.  You may need to adjust the PYTHONPATH to some other location, depending on where your `interface` package actually resides.

Comment: No, by default the script you pass as argument gets its directory extracted and put in `sys.path`, not the current working directory.  But it might be because `interface.py` or the `interface` package is somewhere else, and that other place needs to be manually included in `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @ArminRigo: you're right, thanks, I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: The `interface.py` package is included in:
 `/usr/local/bin/pgs4a-0.9.6/buildlib/interface.py`.

I tried adding that path to the alias suggested by John like so.

`alias pyg='PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/bin/pgs4a-0.9.6 python /usr/local/bin/pgs4a-0.9.6/android.py python /usr/local/bin/pgs4a-0.9.6/buildlib/interface.py'`

Is that what you meant?

Comment: I think  you want `/usr/local/bin/pgs4a-0.9.6/buildlib` in your `PYTHONPATH` then, because interface.py is in that directory.  And no, you must not say "python" twice in the alias!  Try just running this manually: `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/bin/pgs4a-0.9.6/buildlib python` then do `import interface` and see if it works.  If it does, that's the right `PYTHONPATH`.